# Postfix sending mail from hostname

Tags: smtp, subdomain, postfix-mta, hostname, squirrelmail

heey all,

I'm having a question regarding postfix and how it sends mail.
I've set up correctly and i'm able to send mail which doesn't end up in spam.

But for some reason when i show details of the mail (on gmail for example) it shows this a sender address: **user@mail.domain.com**

I want this to become **user@domain.com**
How would i do such a thing?

Another question from me is how would one encrypt the email? Without it going directly to the spam folder?

I'm using **mailutils** to send my mail as **squirrelmail** somehow **can't** send my mail. Yet squirrelmail can view the mail.
I'm using Debian Jessie as my server

My postfix main file:

```
myhostname = mail.domain.com
mydomain = domain.com
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = $myhostname, $mydomain, localhost, localhost.$mydomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
relay_domains = $mydestination
syslog_name=postfix/submission

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
#smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_wrappermode=no

smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#Security and Anti-Spam cinfig
policy-spf_time_limit = 3600s
smtpd_helo_required = yes

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
 reject_non_fqdn_recipient
 reject_unknown_recipient_domain
 permit_mynetworks
 permit_sasl_authenticated
 reject_unauth_destination
 check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf
 check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023

smtpd_helo_restrictions =
 permit_mynetworks
 reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
 reject_invalid_helo_hostname

smtpd_client_restrictions=
 permit_mynetworks
 permit_sasl_authenticated
 reject_unknown_client_hostname

smtpd_data_restrictions =
 reject_unauth_pipelining

#DKIM
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891

local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only answer your first question, you'll want "Address Rewriting" rules, you can find here how to set them up:

http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html

Comment: Thanks man exactly what i needed but  now my mail ends up in spam hmm gotta redo the steps of dkim i think.

Comment: Redoing the steps of Dkim helped me out and now it's not in spam anymore.
I do have to add all my users to this file right? Or is there a generic way to say allusers@host.domain.com should be allusers@domain.com. Where allusers is not the collection of all users available for mailing.